# Unexpected token '<' Error when installing a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-native

Note:
before you mark the question as duplicate please let me know where the actual answer is. I have gone through 10 different questions but none of them seems to truly address the issue in hand.

Hi all,
I have installed the module called speedometer chart on the reactJS. however, there seems to be an issue with the library. 
when I execute the code I get this error and cannot figure out how to resolve it.

```
./node_modules/react-native-speedometer-chart/src/index.js
SyntaxError: /node_modules/react-native-speedometer-chart/src/index.js: Unexpected token (16:4)

>  14 |
>  15 |   const percentElement = (showPercent) ? (
>  16 |     <Text style={[styles.percentText, percentStyle]} numberOfLines={1}>{percentValue}%</Text>
>     |     ^
>  17 |   ) : null;
>  18 | 
>  19 |   const textElement = ((showText) && (text)) ? (
```

Comment: It's probably because the jsx transpiler is not running `<` is not a valid javascript token

Comment: @brein what should it be replaced with?

Comment: I need more info because it depends on how you set up your project.. Do other react components work well?